# How to get grid items --wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I made WPF application named as `WpfApplication7`.It has several folders. One of them is named as `Assign_Rights` . I have created a UserControl in this folder and named it as `Assignment_Rights`. Inside this user control i have created a grid    and bind it to data explicitly! Now There is button name as `Click New`. It shows me that `PK(Primary Key-Value)` of a `selected item` from grid.

```
User n = grid.GetRow(view.FocusedRowHandle) as User;
int abc = n.Primary_Key;
```

Question:  As i wrote code to get PK of Selected item it generated error at 
`int abc = n.Primary_Key;`

by saying

`Error  'WpfApplication7.Assign_Rights.User' does not contain a definition for 'Primary_Key' and no extension method 'Primary_Key' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication7.Assign_Rights.User' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Backup_WPFAppliacation7\New folder\WpfApplication7\WpfApplication7\Assign_Rights\Assignment_Rights.xaml.cs   59  28  WpfApplication7`

How to Solve this Error?

**EDIT**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Core;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Grid;
namespace WpfApplication7.Assign_Rights
    {
    public partial class Assignment_Rights : UserControl
        {
        int useridd;
        nrcsaEntities d = new nrcsaEntities();
        public Assignment_Rights()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
           }


        private void ToggleButton1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
            if (view.IsRowSelected(view.FocusedRowHandle) == false)
                {
                DXMessageBox.Show("Please Select any Item From Grid List");
                }

            else
                {

                User n = grid.GetRow(view.FocusedRowHandle) as User;
               int abc = n.Primary_Key;

                var getd = from p in d.Users select p;

                MessageBox.Show(view.FocusedRowHandle.ToString());
                } . . . .
```

Comment: can you share User class?

Comment: Sure. one minute please

Comment: actually I wanted to see the User entity class....that should have Primary_Key (int) defined in it

Comment: @nit It has. I am using same logic in my second usercontrol, there it is working very fine.

Comment: this is weird. Can you debug the code by commenting the line giving error and see what is coming in n after  User n = grid.GetRow(view.FocusedRowHandle) as User;

Comment: `what is coming in n after ` means?

Comment: you are getting value of 'grid.GetRow(view.FocusedRowHandle) as User' in variable 'n'. Wanted to know what is it when the able line executes

Comment: n is selected row object

Comment: I had same error! there must be two classes in your application with same names and variables(datatypes/names)!. Remove one of them.